# Ожидание обновления AD в PowerShell

Tags: powershell, active-directory, exchange

Добрый день.

Столкнулся с такой проблемой: при создании объекта в AD/Exchange через скрипт PowerShell этот объект иногда создаётся с задержкой и поэтому не получается его сразу использовать, т.е.:

```
$contact = New-MailContact -Name ... -ExternalEmailAddress ...
New-InboxRule -Mailbox ... (условия) -RedirectTo $contact
```

на второй строке через раз получаю ошибку что New-InboxRule должно выполнять хоть какое-то действие (т.е. коммандлет не находит в AD переданный ему $contact). Очевидным решением кажется вставить sleep между командами, но это сильно замедлит скрипт (если брать время с запасом), особенно если таких контактов много.

Вопрос: как можно правильно синхронизировать продолжение выполнения скрипта с обновлением AD?

Я пока пришёл к этому:

```
$sync = Get-MailContact -Identity ...
while (!$sync) {    
  sleep 1
  $sync = Get-MailContact -Identity ...
}
```

Но, возможно, есть более правильный/простой способ ?..

Comment: А можете показать ошибку?

Comment: Увы, уже нет, т.к. задача решена, вопрос был на будущее. Но суть в том, что $contact указывает вроде как на уже созданный объект, но exchange его не видит. Такая же фигня происходит если вызвать New-Mailbox сразу после New-ADUser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В общем, случайно нашёл ответ на вопрос. Оказывается, если в сети есть несколько домен-контроллеров, то в одном PowerShell скрипте два подряд идущих командлета могут обращаться к **разным** домен-контроллерам. А так как репликация не мгновенная, то второй командлет обламывается и не видит результата выполнения предыдущего.

Решение: указывать в командлете конкретный домен-контроллер, с которым он должен работать, через `-DomainController <FQDN>`.

Answer (score 1):

Это нормальная ситуация. Так называемый "proxy address" в Active Directory не появляется моментально и требуется некоторое время. Я бы сделал так:

```
$contact = New-MailContact -Name ... -ExternalEmailAddress ...
Update-Recipient $contact
New-InboxRule -Mailbox ... (условия) -RedirectTo $contact
```